# Return is deleting my inputted string value

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and programming in general, I am still learning the very basics of how to program but I want to improve. I will attach the full code below.

I have two questions:

1. I tried to run debugging in Visual Studio and what I found out is that my `return` statements are deleting the values of my `userName` and `userPass`, can someone please explain why?
2. How is the structure of my code and my functions? Am I doing it right by putting most of the logic inside of the `setName` and `setPw` functions or should I do something different, perhaps it is better to put the std::cin input code outside of functions? I understand there are many ways you can go around programming something but I just wonder if I'm doing it right or not structure-wise.

Expected Result:

- Console outputs username which the user inputs
- Console outputs password which the user inputs

Problem:
Whenever I input the values of `userName` and `userPass` the console output always comes back empty.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

//Program idea: The user inputs their username and password and the system outputs it back on the console

class userRegistration
{
public:
    std::string setName(std::string userName);
    std::string setPw(std::string userPass);
};

std::string userRegistration::setName(std::string userName) {

    std::cin >> userName;
    
    return userName;
}

std::string userRegistration::setPw(std::string userPass) {

    std::cin >> userPass;

    return userPass;
}

int main()
{
    std::string userName = "";
    std::string userPass = "";

    userRegistration u;

    //Username Section
    std::cout << "Please enter your username: \n";
    u.setName(userName);

    //Password Section
    std::cout << "Please enter your password: \n";
    u.setPw(userPass);

    //Output
    std::cout << "Your username is: " << userName << "\n";
    std::cout << "Your password is: " << userPass << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the values returned from the function. You got confused by two totally different object having the same name existing in different scopes. I removed most of it:

> ```
> std::string userRegistration::setName(std::string userName) {
>     std::cin >> userName; 
>     return userName;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     std::string userName = "";
>     userRegistration u;
>
>     u.setName(userName);
>
> }
> ```

`userName` in `main` is one string. When you call `u.setName(userName)` then that string is copied. Insided the function you have a second string called `userName`. That string is distinct from the one in `main`. You read user input in the `userName` in the function and return it. Though, in main you ignore the return value. If you use the return value you'd see the change also in `main`:

```
userName = u.setName(userName);
```

However, you seem to be conflating two concepts of getting stuff out of a function.

You should either simply use the value returned from the function. In that case there is no need to pass an empty string to the function:

```
std::string userRegistration::getName() {
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x; 
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    
    userRegistration u;

    std::string userName = u.getName();

}
```

Or, alternatively you let `u.setName(userName)` write to the string it gets passed. In that case the string has to be passed by reference  and there is no point to return something:

```
void userRegistration::setName(std::string& x) {
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x; 
}

int main()
{
    
    userRegistration u;
    std::string userName;
    u.setName(userName);

}
```

However, you should prefer to return values rather than using out-reference parameters.

Comment: Typo: `std::string userName = u.getName(userName);` should be `std::string userName = u.getName();`

Answer (score 1):

As is very common with newbies you've got yourself confused over parameters, return values and calling functions. There is no need for `setName` to take a parameter, it returns a value, it does not accept a value.

Here's how it should look using a local variable instead of a parameter

```
std::string userRegistration::setName() {
    std::string userName; // local variable
    std::cin >> userName;
    return userName;
}
```

The second issue is that you must use the return value in your calling code.

```
userName = u.setName();
```

A couple of other points, the function `setName` does not set anything at all, `getName` or `inputName` would be better names.

The class `userRegistration` has no purpose at all. It should be removed and your functions can simply be written as global functions. Here's how that would look

```
std::string setName() { // global function
    std::string userName; // local variable
    std::cin >> userName;
    return userName;
}

userName = setName(); // call global function
```

Note that in the code above there are two variables called `userName`. That is not a requirement for this code to work. You could rename either variable and the code would still work fine (newbies often get confused over this point as well).

Answer (score -1):

Two way you can solve this issue
First, take another string variable to avoid same name confusion.

```
//Username Section
    std::cout << "Please enter your username: \n";
    std::string getuserName = u.setName(userName);

    //Password Section
    std::cout << "Please enter your password: \n";
    std::string getuserPass = u.setPw(userPass);
  
   std::cout << "Your username is: " << getuserName << "\n";
   std::cout << "Your password is: " << getuserPass << "\n";
```

Second, pass userName,userPass as reference in function

void userRegistration::setName(std::string &userName) {

```
    std::cin >> userName;   
    
}

void userRegistration::setPw(std::string &userPass) {

    std::cin >> userPass;
    
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `std::void` is not legal C++.